# jQuery slider won't set volume on chromeless YouTube player

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have a chromeless YouTube player that I want to control using a jQuery slider but when I try to slide the slider it doesn't set volume for the player. It also refuses to move after I add `setVolulme(ui.value);` to the code. Any ideas on how to make this work or what is wrong with it?

```
$(function()
    $("#volume").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 75,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            setVolulme(ui.value);
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });

    $("#amount").val($("#volume").slider("value"));
});

function setVolulme(newVolume) {
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.setVolulme(newVolume);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `ytplayer` variable coming from? Is it global?

Comment: ytplayer is the id of the chromeless youtube player object:

<object data="https://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&amp;video_id=OxzucwjFEEs&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer;autoplay=1" id="ytplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="1" width="1">

other functions with this variable work in the same manner, ie:

function muteS() {
  if(ytplayer) {
    ytplayer.mute();
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function setVolulme(newVolume) {
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.setVolulme(parseInt(newVolume));
    }
}
```